# How to make a mobile site work like Linkedin mobile inbox?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

Hi I am trying to copy the way [linkedin mobile](http://touch.www.linkedin.com/#inbox) works on IOS, but I not getting it right.

How can you make the top part fixed like that and the scroll only happen in a DIV bellow a fixed DIV ?

What would be a minimal setup to do that ? is there any JS involved, or just HTML and CSS can do that (I looked at the page and it looks like there is JS) ?

Thanks !

Comment: tired simply having the header position absolute and the body with a padding from the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer...

http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui.html#layout

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS with the following tags `position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;` ?